# ScrewTurn Wiki send an email to all users when a new page is added or an existing modified

Tags: notifications, sendmail, screwturn

I'm searching how to configure screwturnwiki to send an email message to all users when a new page is added or an existing page is modified.
Could someone help me to find a solution?
Thank you for your help.
Best regards
Fab

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't do exactly what you are asking out of the box.  However, here is what you can do:

- You can flag individual pages to receive email updates when changes are made or subscribe to an RSS update feed on a page by page basis (top right corner icons).
- You can subscribe to a global/namespace RSS update feed for new/updated pages using the RSS icons on the top left corner.
- You could write a custom plug-in to provide the functionality you are looking for.  Here is a link to available plug-ins but I don't see one that fits your need: [Screwturn Customizing](http://www.screwturn.eu/Customize.MainPage.ashx)

Comment: a plugin might be the best answer for this if you don't want to rely on users subscribing to feeds